# Are $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(f)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(g)$ isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have the following problem. Let $f(x) = x^3+5$ and $g(x) = x^3+2$. Prove that these two polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$. Are the fields $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(f)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(g)$ isomorphic?

I have already prove by inspection that $f$ and $g$ doesn't have roots over $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$, so they're irreducible. My questions are

- The fact that $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(f)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(g)$ are fields follow directly because $f$ and $g$ are irreducible so $(f)$ and $(g)$ are maximal?
- Is there an easier way to prove that the polynomials are irreducible?
- $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(f)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(g)$ are isomorphic because $(f), (g)$ generate the same ideal because they're monic?

Thanks

Comment: Note that $5\equiv-2\pmod7$

Comment: You can either argue by using that both have the same size $7^3$, or by giving an explicit isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^3+5)\to\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^3+2)$ by sending $x\mapsto 3x$.

Comment: @plop:  from my comment, shouldn't the isomorphism send $x\mapsto6x$?

Comment: I would prefer $x\mapsto -x$. An unexperienced user would try to figure out what is $6^3\bmod 7$ which is harder than $(-1)^3=-1$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner "The" isomorphism? There is no such thing.

Comment: Yes, @plop, I realized later that each of $x\mapsto nx$ where $n\in\{3,5,6\}$ is an isomorphism, since $3^3\equiv5^3\equiv6^3\equiv-1\pmod7$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner how do you get that they are an isomorphism from the fact that those numbers are $-1 (mod 7)$?

Comment: @plop How do you know that the size is $7^3$ and why is $x \rightarrow 3x$ an isomorphism? Thanks

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^3+5)$ (or the other one) each has a representative that is the remainder of any of its elements after division by $x^3+5$. Since this has degree $3$, the remainders have degree up to $2$. So, polynomials like $ax^2+bx+c$, with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_7$. There are $7^3$ of those.

Comment: To show that $x\mapsto 3x$ is an isomorphism, you can do the following. Look at it as a map $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]\to\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^3+2)$ and compute its kernel. We have that $x^3+5$ gets mapped to $3^3x^3+5=-x^3+5=-(x^3-5)=-(x^3+2)=0\in\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^3+2)$. Therefore, $x^3+5$ is in the kernel. Since $x^3+5$ is irreducible, then that is the generator of the kernel.

Comment: @plop So now you are using something like $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/ker(\phi) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^3+2)$ (with $\phi(x) = 3x$) is always an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, the [ring isomorphism theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(groups)), the first one.

Comment: @plop but know I have to prove that $\phi(x)$ is a surjective morphism. I can see that is a morphism, but in order to prove the surjectivity, what is the form of the elements $q \in \mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^3+2)$? $q$ is something of the form $q(x) = r(x)(x^3+2)$ with $r(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_7[x]$?

Comment: The elements of the quotient are of  the form $r(x)+\{(x^3+2)p(x):\ p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_7[x]\}$. Showing that it is surjective can be done by showing that you can get $1$, as the image of $1$ and $x$ as the image of $5x$. All other elements of the codomain are sums and products of $1$ and $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes, $(f)$ and $(g)$ are maximal ideals, and as you were told their quotients are fields with the same number of elements.
  A direct approach to show that they are isomorphic is to consider the homomorphism which is identity on $\mathbb Z_7$ and maps $x$ to $-x$.
- I don't know an easier way to show that $f$ and $g$ are irreducible.
- No, $(f)\neq(g)$.

Comment: Can you explain to me a little bit what the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(f)$ look like? I know that $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$ is $\{a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n: a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_7\}$, does that mean $a_i \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ ?